2012 Mazda 6 Low Beams Blindspot
I just changed both of the low beam bulbs.  Ever since there is a large blind spot right down the center whenever I am driving at night where it is not safe to drive.  It’s as though the low beams are angled out, but they don’t look like it.  I do not believe there is a a horizontal headlight adjustment (only vertical).  Does anyone have any ideas?
Update:
I put in these-
https://www.autozone.com/collision-body-parts-and-hardware/headlight/p/sylvania-silverstar-ultra-headlight-bulb-h7su-2/946950_0_0

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you replace the bulbs with anything besides a stock replacement? Like LEDs or whatever?

Perhaps you didn't seat one of the bulbs properly.
